# How to add Angular Material in exists project?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material2

I have created Angular 2 project.

I tried to add **Angular Material** in exists project using this npm command([official documentation](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)):

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

After installed I get a lot of errors when I tried to launch `npm server`. Seem it does not work directly with exists project.

How to add Angular Material correctly in project?
I use also: `Yarn, Webpack`

Comment: Share your `package.json`

Comment: As @Nehal mentioned, your `package.json` and the errors you're seeing will help us troubleshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot help with `Yarn` or `Webpack`. But the article I have found most useful in getting Angular Material to work is this]
[setting-up-your-first-angular-2-project-using-angular-material2](https://medium.com/@ladyleet/setting-up-your-first-angular-2-project-using-angular-material2-5db18a174165). 
Hope this works for you too.

Comment: This is deprecated: `MaterialModule.forRoot()`, the article needs upgrade

Comment: @OlegP The guide is actually using an older version of Angular Material (aka below `beta.3`)

Comment: It is so sadly, because I tried to add Angular Material in exists project, it involk errors when I start server